# Building a query in Access

Tags: ms-access, time, ms-access-2010

I need to do a query to show how many time a person remained inside the office.
I have a list that create a record of when the person entry in the office and 
record and other records when the person out the office.
I have some difficults because a person can entry/out many times in the same day and sometimes one person not register your entry or out.
Follow the example

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ Local Date ║ Local Time ║      Employee      ║     Office      ║ Catraca ║ Staus ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 10:16      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Duma  ║     002 ║ In    ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 13:03      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ Out   ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 15:19      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ Out   ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 15:25      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ In    ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 18:31      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ Out   ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 18:40      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ In    ║
║ 11/7/2012  ║ 19:56      ║ SILVA ,ANDRE BRAGA ║ Alexandre Dumas ║     004 ║ Out   ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

In this example the person remained 07:09 hours in the office

Regads
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, totaling it up is fairly easy. Eliminating the timestamps without the matching timestamp is more difficult.

As for the totaling: Dates & times are stored internally as numbers. Assuming that no one works through midnight, then all you have to do is add up all the "In" times and subtract that from all the "Out" times. Like thus:

```
SELECT [TotOut]-[TotIn] AS TotHours, *
FROM (SELECT CheckIn.Employee, CheckIn.[Local Date], Sum(CheckIn.[Local Time]) AS [TotIn]
FROM CheckIn
WHERE (((CheckIn.Staus)="In"))
GROUP BY CheckIn.Employee, CheckIn.[Local Date])  AS TotIn INNER JOIN (SELECT CheckIn.Employee, CheckIn.[Local Date], Sum(CheckIn.[Local Time]) AS [TotOut]
FROM CheckIn
WHERE (((CheckIn.Staus)="Out"))
GROUP BY CheckIn.Employee, CheckIn.[Local Date])  AS TotOut ON (TotIn.Employee = TotOut.Employee) AND (TotIn.[Local Date] = TotOut.[Local Date]);
```

Eliminating the mismatched times is possible, but difficult. This query does most of it. However, it's skipping the first record so needs adjusting.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.[Local Time], B.[Local Time] AS [Prev Time], A.Staus
FROM CheckIn AS A LEFT JOIN CheckIn AS B ON (A.Employee = B.Employee) AND (A.[Local Date] = B.[Local Date])
WHERE (((B.[Local Time])=DMax("[local time]","[checkin]","[local time] < #" & [a].[Local Time] & "#")) AND ((A.Staus)<>[b].[staus]))
ORDER BY A.[Local Time];
```

Also, you'll want to FIRST create a recordset that skips any records that start with the status of "Out". [Here's an article that may help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx).

Comment: Hi Tom Collins Thanks a lot for your help, your instructions are perfects. Now I need to know more about above query with Dlookup, Max, & Iff because I will have many cases where a person not register your entry or out office. One detail I include a format intruction in the start of the codigo SELECT format([TotOut]-[TotIn],"hh:mm") AS TotHours Do you think this can to create some probleme in the future?
Regards
André

Comment: Yes, in the end, you'll want to format the time. Otherwise 7:09 will show up as 0.2979167. I also added to my answer above.